# 16000 to 44100 resampling using speex(Sampling Rate conversion)

Tags: ffmpeg, media, codec, speex

I m doing resampling from 16000 to 44100 Hz using speex. 
Also i did resampling between 16000 to 44100 Hz using ffmpeg.
speex is taking more time for resampling conversion.
Also found that speex is better for multiple of 8000 sampling frequency.
Can any one tell what API should be used for 16000 to 44100 resampling using speex so that it will give better performance than ffmpeg.

Comment: libswresample from ffmpeg is very good. I doubt that the built in speex resampler can give better performance.

Comment: You may also want to investigate the [SoX Resampler (libsoxr)](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFmpeg%20and%20the%20SoX%20Resampler) which ffmpeg supports.